# Probability of binomial distribution

Tags: combinatorics

Here's the question No.8 from 2020 summer semester test of Auckland University.

> You have a box with lots of sticks of four colours: black, white, red and blue. There are equal number of sticks of each colour. That is, if you pick one stick then any colour will be equally probable. What is the probability to take two sticks of the same colour from the box? (You have to pick the sticks both at once.)
>
> (a) $\frac4{\binom53}$
> (b) $4\frac{\binom53}{4\cdot3}$
> (c) $\frac4{\binom42}$
> (d) $\frac1{4\cdot3}$

I have an argument with my instructor, that is, my instructor agree that the answer is 2/5, but I think the answer should be 1/4. We argued if the probability of all 10 outcomes are same.

Screenshot here:

[image]

Could somebody tell me which is the correct answer? $2/5$ or $1/4$?

Comment: @DevashsihKaushik This question has context. Don't template blindly!

Answer (score 3):

> You have to pick the sticks both at once.

It actually does not matter whether the sticks are picked at once or they are picked consecutively, because *there are a large number of sticks*. Effectively the probabilities of picking the colours do not change when going from the first stick to the second, so we may treat the two-stick pick as two independent one-stick picks, and then the probability both sticks are the same colour is the same as the probability the second stick matches colour with the first, which is $\frac14$. Your instructor is wrong.